# Perform different actions depending of the opened template

Tags: php, smarty

I have 3 template pages (`smarty templates`) and 1 PHP file with conditions that show different data depending of the opened page.

directory `smarty`

1. `page1.tpl`
2. `page2.tpl`
3. `page3.tpl`

directory `public_html`

1. `file.php`

Here is the `file.php`

```
if( stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'page1.php' )) {
    
     echo 'page1';
} else if( stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'page2.php' )) {

     echo 'page2';
} else if( stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'page3.php' )) {

     echo 'page3';
}
```

Now when I open `https://example.com/page1.php` should go in first condition and echo me page1. This doesn't happen. It is showing me blank page.

I guess this is happening because I don't actually have file called `page1.php`. If I create even empty `page1.php` file all is working but the idea is to have all in one page `file.php` and show different data based on opened page.

What I'm trying to do in `file.php` is to get the url and if ends `page1.php` show data for page1 and so on.

Is this how should be done or there is another way?

Comment: Have you turned on error reporting? If not, it is possible that you have an error in your code and nothing is displayed.

Comment: Yes, no errors or anything. Just blank page because I guess there is not actual file `page1.php` and when I try to open `https://example.com/page1.php` shows empty/blank page. Even that I have content in the `if` condition

Comment: I wonder if there is something I can add like a session or something but this will still suggest that I should have actual file. I'm not sure.

Comment: Have you redirected  the requests from `page1.php` to `file.php`  (e.g. on Apache via `mod_rewrite`)? Otherwise nothing would be executed when the file `page1.php` isn't present.

Comment: I didn't redirect the request. I hoped that it would be possible if I just take the URL and check which page is after the `https://example.com/`..

Comment: You have to address a file that can be executed. Otherwise nothing happens. Maybe pointing to https://example.com/file.php?p=page1.php works. But in this case it would be better to check the get parameters in your scritp (i.e. `if ($_GET['p'] == 'page1.php') ...` insted of `if( stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'page1.php' ))`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/243437/discussion-between-schmauch-and-jason-wung).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you redirected the requests from page1.php to file.php (e.g. on Apache via mod_rewrite)? Otherwise nothing would be executed when the file page1.php isn't present.

Maybe pointing to example.com/file.php?p=page1.php works. But in this case it would be better to check the get parameters in your script. For example:

```
if (isset($_GET['p']) { $page = $_GET['p']; }

if ($page == 'page1.php') ...
```

For the latter you could consider to use a [`switch` statement](https://www.php.net/manual/de/control-structures.switch.php).

Comment: Thanks for the help! For the switch you mean instead of `if` - `else if`?